# react-native : cannot find module 'npmlog'

Tags: node.js, windows, react-native

I am trying to install react native on my windows 7 PC,
but unfortunately an error occurred during installation saying

> Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'

```
npm install -g react-native-cli //Success
react-native init AwesomeProject//missing module
```

Note that my node version is 4.3.1

What is missing?!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you possibly have a conflict with your npm version and your node version.

Re-installing node *usually* solves this issue.

I won't list them all, but a google search of the error will throw up hundreds of results. You can try fixing paths yourself, but generally best just to let the node installer handle it.

Re-installing npm may also resolve the issue

`npm install -g npm`